# Can't not use ListCellRenderer

Tags: java, swing, netbeans

I'm using Netbeans to develop my Java application.I want to display list of items with icons. I have use **ListCellRendere**r but it just display item, but not icon.
Here is my code

//Item class

```
public class Item {
  private String title;
  private String imagePath;
  private ImageIcon image;
  //getter and setter}
```

//ItemRenderer

```
public class ItemRenderer  extends JLabel implements ListCellRenderer{

  private static final Color HIGHLIGHT_COLOR = new Color(0, 0, 128);

  public ItemRenderer() {
    setOpaque(true);
    setIconTextGap(12);
  }
public Component getListCellRendererComponent(JList list, Object value, int index, boolean isSelected, boolean cellHasFocus)
{   try
    {
        Item  item = (Item)value;
        System.out.println("hhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhh" + item.getTitle() + ";icon=" + item.getImagePath());
        setText(item.getTitle());
        setIcon(item.getImage());

        if (isSelected)
        {
          setBackground(HIGHLIGHT_COLOR);
          setForeground(Color.white);
        }
        else
        {
          setBackground(Color.white);
          setForeground(Color.black);
        }
    }
    catch(UnsupportedOperationException ex)
    {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet.");
    }
    return this;
}
```

//and here is my code to use ListCellRenderer

```
 public frmMain() {
    initComponents();

    DefaultListModel model = new DefaultListModel();

    Item [] items = null;
    items = new Item[5];

    for(int i=0;i<5;i++)
    {
        items[i] = new Item();
        items[i].setTitle("Item " + i);
        items[i].setImagePath("pdf-gif.gif");

        model.addElement(items[i]);
    }

    lstLeftItems.setModel(model);

    lstLeftItems.setCellRenderer(new ItemRenderer());
    lstLeftItems.setVisibleRowCount(5);


}
```

Notes: lstLeftItems is a Jlist.

Pls help me to fix this bug.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the code you provide, the Icon is null. I see where you set the title and imagePath, but nowhere to you actually read the image file to create the icon.

If you need more help post your [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) so we can see the real problem.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your answer. I did not set image beacause of my getter method for Image attribute
Here is my code

```
 public ImageIcon getImage() {

    if(image==null)
    {
        image = new ImageIcon(imagePath);
    }
    return image;
}
```

So, just set imagePath is enough.